# How do I redirect an English language URL to an Arabic language URL?

Tags: php, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a link that's currently formatted like this:

```
http://example.com/news/view/1.html
```

I want to it redirect it to:

```
http://example.com/خبر/عنوان-الخبر
```

where `خبر` is equal to `news`  and 
 `عنوان-الخبر` is the title of the news page. I want ro do it using .htaccess, and provide a permanent 301 redirect for the old URLs.

Do I need to edit the PHP source at all to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one off you just make sure your terminal is in UTF-8 mode, then paste the Arabic into a `RedirectMatch` as normal.

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/news/view/1\.html /خبر/عنوان-الخبر
```

If you wanted it dynamic (i.e. some database which lets you know the title of `1.html`) then yes, that would need some PHP.

But if you are saying that `1.html` is actually the correct URL, and you just want to change the text that appears in the browser address bar, I don't think that can be done

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have to edit the PHP source, I suppose not.

I'd try do that with mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/view/1\.html$ /خبر/عنوان-الخبر [R=301,L]
```